# Calling a overloaded constructor with null argument

Tags: java

The no argument constructor will throw an error because the compiler doesn't know which constructor to call. What is the solution?

```
private Test() throws Exception {
    this(null);//THIS WILL THROW ERROR, I WAN'T TO CALL A SPECIFIC CONSTRUCTOR FROM THE TWO BELOW. HOW TO DO??
}
private Test(InputStream stream) throws Exception {

}



private Test(String fileName) throws Exception {

}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't work because it doesn't really make sense. What kind of behavior do you expect the constructor with null as argument to have?

Answer (score 5):

Typecast the `null`:

```
private Test() throws Exception {
    this((String)null); // Or of course, this((InputStream)null);
}
```

But it seems a bit odd that you'd want to call `Test(String)` or `Test(InputStream)` with a `null` argument...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why all those constructors, so lovingly crafted, are private.

I'd do it this way:

```
private Test() throws Exception {
    this(new PrintStream(System.in);
}

private Test(InputStream stream) throws Exception {
    if (stream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input stream cannot be null");
    }   
    // other stuff here.
}    

private Test(String fileName) throws Exception {
    this(new FileInputStream(fileName));
}
```